# Convert nested AJAX call to sequential Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, es6-promise

I have code which is successfully running AJAX calls in sequence (a crude internet latency test for my employees):

```
const start = new Date().getTime();
const testUrl = "our server URL";
const start = new Date().getTime();
$.ajax(testUrl + '?delay=0.0&length=100').done(function(){
  $.ajax(testUrl + '?delay=0.1&length=1000').done(function(){
    $.ajax(testUrl + '?delay=0.2&length=10000').done(function(){
      $.ajax(testUrl + '?delay=0.1&length=100000').done(function(){
        $.ajax(testUrl + '?delay=0.2&length=10000').done(function(){
          $.ajax(testUrl + '?delay=0.1&length=1000').done(function(){
            $.ajax(testUrl + '?delay=0.0&length=100').done(function(){
              $.ajax(testUrl + '?delay=0.1&length=10').done(function(){
                const end = new Date().getTime();
                internetTestTime = end - start;
                console.log('Your internet test time: ' + internetTestTime + 'ms')
                })
            })
          })
        })            
      })
    })
  })
});
```

I would like to switch this to use Promises that run in sequence. Here is the progress so far:

```
const start = new Date().getTime();
const testSuiteInputs = [
    {delay: 0.5, length: 100},
    {delay: 0.4, length: 500},
    // more tests here
];
let testSequence = Promise.resolve();
testSuiteInputs.forEach(testSuiteInput => {
    //  something goes here...
});
testSequence.then(() => {
    const end = new Date().getTime();
    internetTestTime = end - start;
    console.log('Your internet test time: ' + internetTestTime + 'ms')
});
```

What do I need to put at  above to make these Promises run sequentially?

Comment: Reworded for clarity, thank you

Comment: Try to spell out the promise chain without using a loop at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest way would be to switch your `.forEach()` loop to a plain `for` loop inside an `async` function and then use `await`:

```
async function run() {
    const start = new Date().getTime();
    const testSuiteInputs = [
        {delay: 0.5, length: 100},
        {delay: 0.4, length: 500},
        // more tests here
    ];
    for (let item of testSuiteInputs) {
        let url = `${testUrl}?delay=${item.delay}&length=${item.length}`;
        let result = await $.ajax(url);
        // process result here
    }
}

run().then(finalResult => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

To do it without using `async/await`, a common design pattern for sequencing asynchronous access to an array is to use `.reduce()` where you just chain promises together:

```
const start = new Date().getTime();
const testSuiteInputs = [
    {delay: 0.5, length: 100},
    {delay: 0.4, length: 500},
    // more tests here
];

testSuiteInputs.reduce((p, item) => {
    return p.then(() => {
        // when previous ajax call finished, start the next one
        let url = `${testUrl}?delay=${item.delay}&length=${item.length}`;
        return $.ajax(url).then(result => {
            // process individual result here
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(finalResult => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});;
```